# redirect -onepage checkout to another page

Tags: onepage-checkout

i am using one page checkout module, but i want place order button to redirect to another page (in my case to the bank where the user will put his credit card information) when transaction is success i need to save the order and call the success.phtml and where to put the files (from the bank)to have access to the mage class?
 can someone please help me with this.

Thank you

Comment: Why not just use the credit card payment option?

Answer (score 4):

This is not a trivial change, and your wanted implementation is incorrect.
What you intend to do is completely bypass the checkout. How do you propose magento to complete the order?

What you really want is to add a payment method, in checkout. This will allow your customer to select the payment method, and get redirected to the bank, in checkout when they click 'make payment'

This would work similar to how paypal redirect works.

Have you looked to see if anyone had created a module for magento for your chosen bank?

If not, you would need to create a payment module to handle this.
There are a lot of resource via google on how to do this.